# Java runtime could not be located no Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Já tenho o JDK instalado, mas o Visual Studio Code não reconhece e apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo fazer para ele reconhecer? Pois já tenho o

> Language Support For Java(TM),
> Debugger for Java,
> Java test Runner,
> Maven for Java,
> Java extension Pack
>
> instalados.

O que devo fazer para o Visual Studio Code saiba o caminho do JDK?

Comment: Você já configurou a variavel de ambiente java?
https://www.devmedia.com.br/preparacao-do-ambiente-para-desenvolvimento-em-java/25188

Comment: Não, mas vou entrar no link que vc mandou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Visual Studio Code olha para as variáveis `JAVA_HOME` e `JDK_HOME`.

No Windows, vá ao Control Panel (Painel de Controle), System (Sistema), Advanced System Settings (Configurações avançadas do sistema) e clique em Environment Variables (Variáveis de ambiente) e sete ambas, apontando para a localização do teu JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Falta configurar as variáveis de ambiente.

> Você pode ver tutorial como configurar nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/4395789

Comment: Seria interessante transcrever a solução no link que apresentou, até pelo facto de ela estar em inglês

Comment: Links a recursos externos são bem-vindos, mas [lembre-se de fornecer um contexto para cada link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para que seus colegas usuários possam ter uma ideia do que se trata e por que está aqui. Sempre destaque a parte mais relevante de um link importante.